# Trying to define a optimizer in TensorFlow, I got an error stating the learning rate has not been defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

The error that I got was

```
ValueError: Missing learning rate, please set self.learning_rate at optimizer creation time.
```

The code that I used was

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

class GradientDescent(keras.optimizers.Optimizer):

  def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001):
    # Initialize parameters
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate

  def apply_gradients(self, grads, vars):
    # Update variables
    for grad, var in zip(grads, vars):
      var.assign_sub(self.learning_rate*grad)

keras.backend.clear_session()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)
model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[8])])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=GradientDescent(learning_rate=0.001))
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=5)
```

I tried changing init to

```
def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001):
    # Initialize parameters
    self._set_hyper('learning_rate', kwargs.get('lr', learning_rate))
```

But then when I do this, I got the error message of 'SGOptimizer' object has no attribute `'_set_hyper'`. Based on the other custom optimizer code I seen, the author don't have to define `_set_hyper`.

Comment: What custom optimizer code are you talking about?

Comment: I am trying to use a custom optimizer instead of ADAM or SGD, so I am using the code above as a proof of concept. But it is giving the error above.

Comment: That does not answer what I asked, I mean in your question you wrote "Based on the other custom optimizer code I seen" What code have you seen?